# Understanding a sentence with "Ving as it does"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Consider this sentence: "Taken together, these effects, occurring as they do in rapid succession, provide a simple interpretation of showers."

Is it correct that omitting "taken together" and "occurring..." does not change its meaning? So at its core the sentence says that the effects provide a simple interpretation.

Then there are "taken together" and "occurring...". Is it correct to paraphrase this sentence as "Because they occur in rapid succession, we can combine these effects to provide a simple explanation of showers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a modification of this sentence, from a 1945 book about cosmic rays:
[Google Books "What are cosmic rays?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Taken%20together,%20these%20effects,%20occurring%20as%20they%20do%20in%20rapid%20succession,%20provide%20a%20simple%20interpretation%20of%20showers.&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLpsOEzfTsAhUWQ80KHd5-CrEQ_AUoAXoECA0QCQ&biw=1100&bih=609&dpr=3)

> Taken together , these effects of Bremsung and of creation, occurring as they do in rapid succession, provide a simple interpretation of the production of showers : An electron traversing matter is decelerated and gives rise to photons;...

The basic meaning is

> These effects provide a simple interpretation...

These are the phrases you are questioning:

The phrase **taken together** is important, because it is the combination of the two cited effects that provide the simple interpretation.

The  phrase **occurring as they do in rapid succession** is also an important qualification. If the effects did not occur in rapid succession, they might not contribute to the interpretation.

So, the phrases do shape the meaning in an important way.

I don't think your paraphrase is wrong, but I don't think it expresses the idea as well as the original.

Comment: Is the intent to say that the rapid succession allows to combine the effects for a simple interpretation? Or is taking the effects together independent from the fact they occur in rapid succession?

Comment: BTW, thanks for the source of the sentence: this way it is much clearer (and showers turn out to be particle showers, not rains)

Comment: Yes, I think the rapid succession of the events justifies grouping them as an explanation.

Comment: Google Books is a marvel.